# Scheme "Merge" function implementation

Tags: scheme

I am trying to create a Merge2 function using Scheme that takes 2 ordered lists and combines them into a single ordered list. For example `(merge2 '(1 3 4) '(2 4 5))` will yield `(1 2 3 4 4 5)`

Here is my attempt at it.. I feel like this should work, where I just check the `min` of each `car` of each list and then append this `min` to the recursive call of `merge2`. Then my base case is when 1 of the lists becomes empty, it should just return the other list to be appended.

```
(define (merge2 a b)
    (if (and (null? a) (null? b))
        `())
    (if (null? a) b)
    (if (null? b) a)

    (display a)
    (display b)

    (if (= (min (car a) (car b)) (car a)) 
        (append (list (min (car a) (car b))) (merge2 (cdr a) b)))

    (if (= (min (car a) (car b)) (car b)) 
        (append (list (min (car a) (car b))) (merge2 a (cdr b)))))
```

This outputs:

> (1 2 4)(2 3 4)(2 4)(2 3 4)(4)(2 3 4)(4)(3 4)(4)(4)()(4) 
>   TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined [merge2, merge2, merge2, merge2, merge2, merge2, car, merge2, merge2, merge2, merge2, merge2, merge2, car, merge2, merge2, merge2, merge2, merge2, merge2, car]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simpler, use the fact that both lists are *sorted* and pick one element from one and advance over it according to which element is greater, until one of the lists ends. This is what I mean:

```
(define (merge lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((null? lst1) lst2)
        ((null? lst2) lst1)
        ((>= (car lst1) (car lst2))
         (cons (car lst2) (merge lst1 (cdr lst2))))
        (else
         (cons (car lst1) (merge (cdr lst1) lst2)))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(merge '(1 3 4) '(2 4 5))
=> '(1 2 3 4 4 5)
```

Comment: this seems really close to what I was going for. I think I just don't have a grasp for the syntax completely yet. Thank you tho

Answer (score 1):

Part of what you may be struggling with is that Scheme, as a functional programming language, is expression-oriented, not imperative.  So, **everything** written in Scheme has a value, even conditional expressions.  Everything is an expression, and is evaluated in order to produce a result.  When you stick to a purely functional programming style (which Scheme **encourages**, but does not strictly enforce) expressions are evaluated to produce a result that can become part of another expression to be evaluated.  Expressions are simply evaluated, and they are not procedures which cause the computer's memory state to somehow change; there are no side-effects in a functional programming style.  So, you should think of conditional processing in terms of conditional expressions.

The nearest counterpart I can think of, from the imperative programming world, is the `?:` operator of C or Java.  Your function started out with a series of conditional expressions, but those are like a series of conditional expressions in C or Java which aren't assigned to anything, and so the results are "thrown away."

Instead, start thinking in these terms:  We wish to merge two lists together, so what does it mean to merge two lists together if one of them is empty?  This forms a sort of "base case" or terminating condition for the iterative process of merging the two lists.

Also:  What does it mean to merge together two lists if neither of them is empty?  If we can express a solution in terms of smaller lists based on the existing lists (i.e., an inductive step) then we have a start on what a recursive process might look like.

So, part of the solution for this inductive step would involve some kind of expression which are based on examining the `car` of each list to see which one should be placed at the head of the merging of the lists which remain.  If the `(car a)` is smaller than or equal to `(car b)` then `(car a)` can become the first element of `(merge2 (cdr a) b)`, right?  This assumes that there is a way to calculate `(merge (cdr a) b)`, of course!

So, it sounds like we are talking about a conditional expression which would become part of a larger definition or expression which says what it means to merge together two lists:

```
(cond ((<= (car a) (car b)) (cons (car a) (merge2 (cdr a) b) ) )
       ...there's more to write here to finish the conditional expression )
```

I hope this helps make a bit more clear how Oscar Lopez might have derived his solution; you can see that the conditional expression I started writing above is also in the function he presented!

A key part of it all is to think in terms of recursive processes and recursive definitions.